# Get values from .NET controls to SharePoint List

Tags: .net, sharepoint, controls

May I know how can I retrieve the values from .NET front-end control fields to be stored in a SharePoint list?

`Field1`: `TextBox type`

`Field2`: `DropDownList type`

`Field3`: `checkbox type`

Below is my attempt for the `textbox type` field:

```
item["Field1"] = (Field1.ToString());
```

May I know can I retrieve `DDL` and `CB` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample demo to save data to SharePoint by CSOM.

```
<div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Field1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Field2" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Field3" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="btn_Save" runat="server" Text="Button" />


using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp:12001/"))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("lee","pw","domain");
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList3");
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                oListItem["Title"] = Field1.Text;
                oListItem["Field2"] = Field2.SelectedItem.Value;
                oListItem["Field3"] = Field3.Checked;
                oListItem.Update();

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```